# Can I use relays with 10A125V~ for my 220V~ applications, safely?

Tags: voltage-level, relay, current, safety, electricity

I am using the [TinkerKit Relay Module](http://store.arduino.cc/product/T010010) and recently they changed the relay mounted on the board from a white one with `10A250V~` to a black one with `10A125V~`.

In my country the voltage is `220V~`. Can I use the black relay in my application, safely? May be there problems that I have to be careful?

Comment: Definitely no!!!

Comment: Though it will most likely work, `safely` is wrong. If it is rated at 125V, it will work `safely` up to 125V only :)

Comment: In fact the answer is maybe. It all depends on the detailed relay specifications. Many relays have a current rating at one voltage, and a lower rating at a higher voltage. There is, of course, a maximum voltage, independent of current and vice versa.

Comment: The link is not good. Are you using this T010010 model? http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/processor-microcontroller-development-kits/7485360/

Answer (score 1):

The part is obsolete now according to [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Arduino/T010010/?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduia6R6na02v8WdqPh%252bg5WbwIxjODzSpP4DYszJBtcfl8A%3D%3D).  The simple answer is no, you cannot use a 120 volt part at 220 volts.  The higher voltage can breakdown the lower voltage rated parts.  It really has nothing to do with the "power" rating as there will be very little power actually dissipated in the relay.  The current handling of the contacts is one issue and that seemingly didn't change but the voltage rating change is basically saying that this part cannot work at 220volts.